# Could not find the correct Provider<List<Store>> above this CustomerHomePage Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

basically I am creating an ecommerce app and in the home page, the app will read the items data from firebase and this error keeps coming up, which can not find the correct Provider above the HomePage Widget.

here is my code:

main.dart:

```
class Bradat extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Brandat',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
      ),
      home: StreamProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) => DatabaseService().getItemesList(),
          catchError: (_, __) => null,
          child: NavigationHomeScreen()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the navigation Home Screen:

```
class NavigationHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationHomeScreenState createState() => _NavigationHomeScreenState();
}

class _NavigationHomeScreenState extends State<NavigationHomeScreen> {
  Widget screenView;
  DrawerIndex drawerIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    drawerIndex = DrawerIndex.HOME;
    screenView = CustomerHomePage();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = Provider.of<List<Abaya>>(context);
    print(items);
    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: DrawerUserController(
            screenIndex: drawerIndex,
            drawerWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
            onDrawerCall: (DrawerIndex drawerIndexdata) {
              changeIndex(drawerIndexdata);
              //callback from drawer for replace screen as user need with passing DrawerIndex(Enum index)
            },
            screenView: screenView,
            //we replace screen view as we need on navigate starting screens like MyHomePage, HelpScreen, FeedbackScreen, etc...
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is my database class:

```
class DatabaseService{

  final CollectionReference userCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("User");
  final CollectionReference itemCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("Item");
  final CollectionReference storeCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("Store");


  Future UpdateUserData(User user) async {
    return await userCollection.document(user.uid).setData({
      'firstName' :user.firstName,
      'lastName' :user.lastName,
      'phoneNumber' :user.phoneNumber,
    });
  }
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get users{
    return userCollection.snapshots();
  }

  Future UpdateItemData(Abaya item) async {
    return await itemCollection.document(item.itemId).setData({
      'title' :item.title,
      'price' :item.price,
      'oldPrice' :item.oldPrice,
      'images' :item.images,
      'colors': item.colors,
      'sizes': item.sizes,
      'storeId': item.storeId,
      'quantity': item.quantity,
    });
  }

  Stream<List<Abaya>>  getItemesList(){
    return itemCollection.snapshots()
        .map((snapShot) => snapShot.documents
        .map((document) => Abaya.fromJson(document.data))
        .toList());
  }

  Future UpdateStoreData(Store store) async {
    return await storeCollection.document(store.idStore).setData({
      'brand' :store.brand,
      'rank' :store.rank,
      'logo' :store.logo,
    });
  }

  Stream<List<Store>>  getStoreList(){
    return storeCollection.snapshots()
        .map((snapShot) => snapShot.documents
        .map((document) => Store.fromJson(document.data))
        .toList());
  }


}
```

this is my item model class:

```
  class Abaya{
  String itemId;
  String title;
  double price;
  double oldPrice;
  List<String> images;
  List<String> colors;
  List<String> sizes;
  int quantity;
  String storeId;


  Abaya({this.itemId,this.title, this.price, this.oldPrice, this.images, this.colors,
  this.sizes, this.quantity, this.storeId});

  Abaya.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJSON)
      : title = parsedJSON['title'],
        price = parsedJSON['price'],
        oldPrice = parsedJSON['oldPrice'],
        images = parsedJSON['images'],
        colors = parsedJSON['colors'],
        sizes = parsedJSON['sizes'],
        storeId = parsedJSON['storeId'],
        quantity = parsedJSON['quantity'];
  }
```

Comment: Have you declared your `provider` above the widget using it ?

Comment: What do you mean? where?